How to pass a tl or seq containing & to a function?
I am using CSVsimple to make a catalogue of products, each having a variable sized table with different header. So first I scan the file for header-names, save these in variables and then later feed these to the table as a parameter.
Currently I make the table through a string case, and while it is functional, it is unwieldy in the code. (My actual code has more cases than below.)
\str_case_e:nnF{}{
    {\l_Ha_tl}  {\placetable        {#1}    {}                              }
    {\l_Hb_tl}  {\placetable        {#1}    {\l_Ha_tl&}                     }
    {\l_Hc_tl}  {\placetable        {#1}    {\l_Ha_tl&\l_Hb_tl&}            }   
    }           {\placetable        {#1}    {\l_Ha_tl&\l_Hb_tl&\l_Hc_tl&}   }

I thought I could make it easier by giving the headers in a seq- or tl-variable and feed that into the function, like so:
\int_step_inline:nnn{1}{3}{ \tl_if_empty:cF{l_H\int_to_alph:n{##1}_tl}{ \seq_gput_right:Nv \l_head_seq {l_H\int_to_alph:n{##1} _tl}}    }
      \tl_gset:Ne \l_head_tl {\seq_use:Nn \l_head_seq {&}}
      \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_head_tl {&}  
      \placetable{#1} {\l_head_tl}

But when I try
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\l_head_tl ->HeaderAa&HeaderAa2&HeaderAb&

As far as I can tell from looking around, before being used in the intended way, the tl or seq is put into the input stream, that does not know what to do with the alignment tokens. I suppose that is reasonable enough.
However, I have not been able to find if there is a way to give the tl or seq to a function without having it first going to the input stream.
Looking at other answers to similar issues, the answers tend to point in the direction of the \tl_rescan or \char_generate functions, but my experimentation with these has not led anywhere - admittedly I am not sure I fully understand these functions.
Is there a way to pass a seq or tl containing one or more & to a function, without getting the error from the input stream?
My code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc,math}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{testcsv.csv}
ProductType,    ProductSeries,  ProductName,    Header,     Entry,      Header2,    Entry2,     Header3,    Entry3, Bonus
TypeA,      SeriesAA,       NameAAA,        HeaderAa,       BaA,        HeaderAa2,  BaA,        HeaderAb,   bab,        1
TypeA,      SeriesAB,       NameABA,        HeaderAb,       BaA,        ,       ,       ,       ,       2
TypeA,      SeriesAA,       NameAAA,        HeaderAa,       BaA2,       HeaderAa2,  BaA2,       ,       ,       3
TypeA,      SeriesAA,       NameAAB,        HeaderAa,       BaA3,       ,       ,       ,       ,       1
TypeB,      SeriesBA,       NameBAA,        HeaderBa,               Baa,        ,       ,       ,       ,       1
TypeB,      SeriesBA,       NameBAA,        HeaderBa,       BaB,        ,       ,       ,       ,       1
TypeB,      SeriesBA,       NameBAA,        HeaderBa,       BaB,        ,       ,       ,       ,       1
TypeC,      SeriesCA,       NameCAA,        HeaderCa,       BaC,        ,       ,       ,       ,       1
TypeC,      SeriesCA,       NameCAB,        ,           ,       ,       ,       ,       ,       1

\end{filecontents*}


\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_Ha_tl
\tl_new:N \l_Hb_tl
\tl_new:N \l_Hc_tl
\seq_new:N \l_head_seq
\tl_new:N \l_head_tl

\cs_new:Npn \ColCsv #1 {    \use:c {csvcol\romannumeral#1}  }

\NewDocumentCommand\SeqList {mmmo} {
    \seq_if_exist:cF {l_#2_seq} {\seq_new:c {l_#2_seq}}
    \csvreader[#4]{#1}{}{   \seq_if_in:ceF {l_#2 _seq} {\ColCsv{#3}} {\seq_gput_right:ce {l_#2 _seq} {\ColCsv{#3}}} }
}

\cs_new:Npn \headerarray #1#2#3 {
    \csvreader[filter~strcmp={\csvcolii}{#2},and~filter~strcmp={\csvcoliii}{#3}]{#1}{}{
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {4}{2}{8}{ \str_if_eq:eeF {\ColCsv{##1}}{} {\tl_gset:ce {l_H\int_to_alph:n{(##1/2)-1} _tl} {\ColCsv{##1}}}}
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\ListMake{m}{
    \SeqList{#1}{type}{1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_type_seq {
        \SeqList{#1}{serie_##2}{2}[filter~strcmp={##2}{\csvcoli}]
        \seq_map_indexed_inline:cn {l_serie_##2_seq}{
            \SeqList{#1}{name_##2_####2}{3}[filter~strcmp={####2}{\csvcolii}]
            \seq_map_indexed_inline:cn {l_name_##2_####2_seq} {
                \headerarray{#1}{####2}{########2}
                \csvfilterbool{test}{\str_if_eq_p:ee {########2}{\csvcoliii}}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember~picture,overlay]
                    \int_compare:nT {########1=1=####1} {\coordinate(newbox)at([yshift={-3cm}]current~page.north);}
                    \node[draw](Info)at(newbox){                \placecheck{#1}     };
                    \coordinate(newbox)at([yshift=-1cm]Info.south); 
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
        \newpage
    }
}
\cs_new:Npn \placecheck #1 {
%   \int_step_inline:nnn{1}{3}{ \tl_if_empty:cF{l_H\int_to_alph:n{##1}_tl}{ \seq_gput_right:Nv \l_head_seq {l_H\int_to_alph:n{##1} _tl}}    }
%   \tl_gset:Ne \l_head_tl {\seq_use:Nn \l_head_seq {&}}
%   \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_head_tl {&}    
%   
%%  \placetable{#1} {\l_head_tl} %this code does not work, but I would like it to

    \str_case_e:nnF{}{ % This code functions
        {\l_Ha_tl}  {\placetable        {#1}    {}                           }
        {\l_Hb_tl}  {\placetable        {#1}    {\l_Ha_tl&}                  }
        {\l_Hc_tl}  {\placetable        {#1}    {\l_Ha_tl&\l_Hb_tl&}         }  
        }           {\placetable        {#1}    {\l_Ha_tl&\l_Hb_tl&\l_Hc_tl&}}
        
    \seq_gclear:N \l_head_seq \tl_gclear:N \l_Ha_tl \tl_gclear:N \l_Hb_tl   \tl_gclear:N \l_Hc_tl
}

\cs_new:Npn \placetable #1#2 {
     \csvreader [TestTable={#2},test]{#1}{}{%
        \str_case_e:nnF{}
        {
            {\l_Ha_tl}  {\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcolx                     }
            {\l_Hb_tl}  {\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcolv&\csvcolx                }
            {\l_Hc_tl}  {\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcolv&\csvcolvii&\csvcolx     }
        }           {\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcolv&\csvcolvii&\csvcolix&\csvcolx   }
    }
}
\csvstyle{TestTable}{
    no~check~column~count,
    table~head= {Type&Series&Name& #1  Bonus },
    late~after~head=\\,
    late~after~line=\\,
    late~after~last~line=,
    tabularray={
        width=150 mm,
    },
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ListMake{testcsv.csv}
\end{document}


unrelated but \seq_gput_right:Nv \l_head_seq  is wrong, you should never make a global assignment to a local variable

@DavidCarlisle That's true. I've gotten into habit of using global assignments, but I should be vary of that. You reminded me to go through my actual code to set unneccessary globals to locals.

Since I didn't get an answer elsewhere, I can update with my own solution, as I did manage to reduce the code.
Problem seems specifically in passing a "&"-containing tl to the head of the \csvreader, while passing them to the content worked without issue. My workaround was simply to include the head as part of a conditional for the first row, rather than as an actual head. This had the additional effect of removing both the str-case entirely and the \placetable macro completely
My new @placecheck now reads:
\tl_new:N \l_head_tl
\tl_const:Nn \c_mcol_tl {\csvcoli&\csvcolii&} % Mandatory csvinput regardless of case
\tl_new:N \l_col_tl

\cs_new:Npn \@placecheck #1#2 {
    \int_step_inline:nn{3}{\tl_if_empty:cF {l_H \int_to_alph:n{##1} _tl} 
                        {   \tl_put_right:Ne \l_head_tl {\tl_use:c {l_H \int_to_alph:n{##1} _tl} &}
                            \tl_put_right:No \l_col_tl {\ColCsv{\int_eval:n {##1*2+1}} &}           }
                    }
\csvreader [TestTable]{#1.csv}{}{\ifcsvfirstrow{Art.Nr&EAN&Beskrivelse&\l_head_tl Colli \\ \c_mcol_tl \l_col_tl \csvcolxiii} {\c_mcol_tl \l_col_tl \csvcolxiii}}
}

